# Rank rating formula

Tags: ranking, rank

What would be the formula to calculate % rank based on the following data:

1193 Wins
1197 Losses

And as a result I would like to get a % rank something like 92.6%

I would appreciate your help,

thank you.

Comment: Is this a programming question? If so, what language? Also, you need to give a more precise definition of "rank".

Comment: It will be in PHP but I need the formula first. I am not sure how to define the rank. I was thinking something about (Wins / (Wins + Losses)) * 100 But that is too simple for being a rank. So, how to make it more accurate. Maybe to implement some average values.

Comment: It's really up to you how you choose to rank. If you're tracking wins/losses individually, you could even end up with a situation where A wins against B, B wins against C, and C wins against A.

Comment: @snowball how do you think what formula is used here http://www.babevsbabe.com/

Comment: Here's a similar question that addresses your issue: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2119242/voting-algorithm-how-to-calculate-rank